# Segment definitions for linux on x86

Tags: linux-kernel, x86

Linux 3.4.6 defines the following macros in arch/x86/include/asm/segment.h. Can anybody explain why the __USER macros add 3 to the defined constant and why this is not done for __KERNEL macros?

```
#define __KERNEL_CS (GDT_ENTRY_KERNEL_CS*8)
#define __KERNEL_DS (GDT_ENTRY_KERNEL_DS*8)
#define __USER_DS   (GDT_ENTRY_DEFAULT_USER_DS*8+3)
#define __USER_CS   (GDT_ENTRY_DEFAULT_USER_CS*8+3)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These four symbols represent [segment descriptors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_descriptor). The two least-significant bits of these descriptors contain the [privilege level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_level) associated with them, and the third least-significant bit contains the descriptor table type ([GDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Descriptor_Table) or [LDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Descriptor_Table)). This is made clearer by code occurring a little later:

```
/* User mode is privilege level 3 */
#define USER_RPL                0x3
/* LDT segment has TI set, GDT has it cleared */
#define SEGMENT_LDT             0x4
#define SEGMENT_GDT             0x0

/* Bottom two bits of selector give the ring privilege level */
#define SEGMENT_RPL_MASK        0x3
/* Bit 2 is table indicator (LDT/GDT) */
#define SEGMENT_TI_MASK         0x4
```

To achieve this, the descriptor table entry is multiplied by `8`, which shifts it three bits to the left, and then `OR`ed with the table type and privilege level (using addition):

```
/* GDT, ring 0 (kernel mode) */
#define __KERNEL_CS (GDT_ENTRY_KERNEL_CS*8)

/* GDT, ring 3 (user mode) */
#define __USER_CS   (GDT_ENTRY_DEFAULT_USER_CS*8+3)
```